# Can a Retry be configured to retry on null?

Tags: java, resilience4j

I am just starting out with resilience4j and was wondering if it is possible to setup a retry to retry on null results. Here is an example:

```
Retry retry = Retry.ofDefaults("retry");
Retry.decorateSupplier(retry, () -> (String) null).get();
assertThat(retry.getMetrics().getNumberOfSuccessfulCallsWithoutRetryAttempt()).isEqualTo(0);
```

This fails because returning null is ok. Is it possible to configure retry on null.

Comment: Not my strongest area of expertise, so I won't post an answer, but my naive approach would be to wrap whatever code you are running into an extra method/lambda that throws when null is returned. Retry will catch the throw and retry.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing but it would be nice to know if the library has a different solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom `RetryConfig` with your own `retryOnResultPredicate` that returns `true` if `result` is `null`:

```
RetryConfig customConfig = RetryConfig.custom()
    .retryOnResult(response -> response == null)
    .build();
```

Then use it as config parameter when creating a `Retry` instance:

```
Retry retry = Retry.of("retry", customConfig);
Retry.decorateSupplier(retry, () -> (String) null).get();
assertThat(retry.getMetrics().getNumberOfSuccessfulCallsWithoutRetryAttempt()).isEqualTo(0);
```

See also the [resilience4j documentation](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/retry) for more examples.